# Add a line feed in request url

Tags: javascript, browser

```
https://www.something.com?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZUEVHTLQQK3BBSM6%2F20220707%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220707T080637Z&X-Amz-Expires=6000&X-Amz-Signature=e18ed7e584af5f00b7bb451e19e5dd6319998f676ecb006f3cf4528cd1fe3feb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

I plan to add a line feed after the `?` like this:

```
https://www.something.com?
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZUEVHTLQQK3BBSM6%2F20220707%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220707T080637Z&X-Amz-Expires=6000&X-Amz-Signature=e18ed7e584af5f00b7bb451e19e5dd6319998f676ecb006f3cf4528cd1fe3feb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

I have put a `\n` between the `?` and `X`, but it's not working.

need some help, thanks a lot.

this sample:

```js
var str = 'https://sample.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ad/0-frame.json?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZUEVHTLQQK3BBSM6%2F20220707%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220707T080233Z&X-Amz-Expires=6000&X-Amz-Signature=b01777006a08d9d251f46789d50a5873eb5b74eb8580f4af427ffd657d8c45b3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host';

/ ** we can't use regexp to get file extension name **/
str.toLowerCase().match(/[^\.]*$/)[0];
```

but this url like this, we can get it.

```
var str = 'https://sample.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ad/0-frame.json?
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZUEVHTLQQK3BBSM6%2F20220707%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220707T080233Z&X-Amz-Expires=6000&X-Amz-Signature=b01777006a08d9d251f46789d50a5873eb5b74eb8580f4af427ffd657d8c45b3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host'
```

Comment: Why? What do you hope to accomplish with the linefeed? Where is this url used?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius nope,  I want to use this RegExp 
`/[^\.]*$/` to get some info.

Comment: where is this URL being displayed?

Comment: There are better means of processing a url

Comment: @evolutionxbox chrome network general request-url.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes, u are right, but this regexp in a third-party lib, so I can't fix it right now. so I just find some 'smart' way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what the ultimate purpose is but the comment about wanting to `"get some info"` and the fact that this is tagged with Javascript leads me towards suggesting using the [URLSearchParams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) rather than a regex.

```js
let strurl='https://www.something.com?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZUEVHTLQQK3BBSM6%2F20220707%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220707T080637Z&X-Amz-Expires=6000&X-Amz-Signature=e18ed7e584af5f00b7bb451e19e5dd6319998f676ecb006f3cf4528cd1fe3feb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host';
let url=new URL( strurl );
let params=new URLSearchParams( url.href );

// Iterate through all param/value pairs
params.forEach( ( value, key )=>{
  console.log( key, value )
});

// Find a specific value based upon parameter
console.log( 'Specific ----> X-Amz-Signature: %s', params.get('X-Amz-Signature') );

// test if parameter exists
console.log( 'Parameter exists: %s', params.has('banana') );

// just the querystring portion
console.log( 'Querystring: %s', params.toString() )
```

Comment: I knew this way, but this third party lib didn't use it. so ....